# IE opening file explorer on href =""

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvasjs

I just ask a question which was basically I was having a problem of z-index which got resolved now. But there is now another problem which I am facing as when I am clicking back button it is working in IE rather it is opening location of the folder where the particular file exists. Is there a special way to go back to an initial position in IE.

My fiddle is at this location - 
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/adishri22/L2y04bf8/4/)

Anyway I posting my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
<!-- <link type='text/css' rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' /> -->
<style>
#chartContainerpie{
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0px;
}
#chartContainer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#link {
visibility : hidden;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:100;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
  },
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    click: function(e){
       anotherchart();
   },
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerpie", {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    indexLabelFontColor: "white",
    indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
    type: "pie",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
}
function anotherchart () {
 document.getElementById("chartContainerpie").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("link").style.visibility = "visible";
 // alert(  e.dataSeries.type+ ", dataPoint { x:" + e.dataPoint.x + ", y: "+ e.dataPoint.y + " }" );
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainernew", {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    indexLabelFontColor: "white",
    indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div id="chartContainerpie" style="height: 188px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; "></div>
</div>
<div>
  <a id="link" href="">Back</a>
  <div id="chartContainernew" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; "></div>
</div>
<div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By initial position you mean the top of the page?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski no I mean here I am bouncing from one chart to another...so back means going to same initial state when the page loaded

Comment: hitting the browsers back button in any browser will go to the previous page loaded in the browser, not to some arbitrary "state" of the current dynamically generated page

Comment: Did you tried anything already? If so, you should add it to your answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX if you go through my code... I am not talking back button I am talking of an link I provided in my code

Comment: sorry, the phrase "back button" suggests you clicked the "back button" not a link with the text "back" ... still ... it works the same in firefox/chrome/IE(11)/edge ... clicking on the link marked "back" reverts the graph to the initial state

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't understand I have IE 11 but it is not working....

Comment: I have IE11 and the fiddle works in IE11, IE10 and even in IE9 mode

Comment: I also don't understand this...why it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE, empty HTML HREF leads to directory listing. For further information, you can refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848861(v=vs.85).aspx).

Meanwhile you can use

```
<a id="link" href='#' onclick='location.reload(true); return false;'>Back</a>
```

This will refresh the page and you will get your old chart back. 
But there are better ways to do this. Since you are placing one div on another, you can always place one more hidden div which you can show on click while hiding original 2 div.

Comment: Thank you...I will change according to your comments